# ASP.net: Session doesn't work when backward to login page after redirect

Tags: asp.net

I'm working on my project to build a site in asp.net. I have a problem when use Session for login page. 
My login page will check a session to know if user logged in before or not. If they didn't the login form will appear allow them to log in. Otherwise, the logout button will appear.

Everything works fine and after login, the page will redirect to default.aspx and sessions were saved, I know that because the name of the user appears in default page. But at default page if I press back button on my browser to go back to login page, the login form appears where there should be logout button. Then if I press f5 or open login page in other tab, it works ok with logout button.

Can someone help me with this!
Thank you and sorry for my bad English! :)

Answer (score 0):

When navigating backwards, by default, the page state will be as it was before you logged in. Therefore, without a refresh to get that page to check the session state, there is probably not much you can do.

Comment: Thank you! But i think there has to be some solution for this!

Answer (score 0):

The user is sees the page as it is in the browsers cache. That is why you see the login botton instead of the logout. You can disable caching for the page, however then you will have more server load. I has noting to do with losing the session.

To make the awnser more complete as in the comment:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
  Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
  Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1));
  Response.Cache.SetNoStore(); 
}
```

Will prevent the page from being cached on the browser.

Comment: Thank guys, I've solved the problem with this code:
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1));
            Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
        }
It prevents browser to load the page from cache memory!

Answer (score 0):

Put a break point on where you are checking for whether the user is logged in or not (where you determine whether to show 'logout' button or not), and then navigate back after you login.  I'm pretty sure the page is loaded from cache, so the page will look exactly like it was before the user logged in.  You will probably need a javascript solution for this.

Someone has posted the same issue here with a few solutions that they've tried http://forums.asp.net/t/1118630.aspx